# On enforce referential intergrity: tblProduct is already is use by another person or process

Tags: ms-access-2013

Im using Access 2013 for a college course. The problem is that I'm trying to join two related tables using enforced referential integrity. I get an error message that states:"tblProduct is already in use by another person or process". It is not. I don't know how to fix it. SupplierID is the primary key in tblSupplier and the foreign key in tblProduct. I can join the tables but I can't enforce referential integrity and cascade Update related fields, which is what the assignment ask for. Anybody know how I can solve this problem? I'd appreciate any advice.
[image]

Comment: The screen capture shows tblProduct is open in another tab.  Close tblProduct before editing a relationship which applies to it.

Comment: I believe you were correct. I closed the table and reopened the relationship window. When I edited the relationship I was able to use enforced referential integrity and cascade Update related fields. Thank you.